# How to get audio volume (as stream) from WebRTC's MediaStream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, mediastream, flutter-webrtc

I am using [flutter mediasoup client](https://pub.dev/packages/mediasoup_client_flutter) to stream video+audio from the server.
This works well in general.

However, I now want to measure audio level (ie, loud/soft) from the incoming audio stream so that I can display an audio level indicator widget.

The underlying stream is this [webrtc class](https://pub.dev/documentation/webrtc_interface/latest/webrtc_interface/MediaStream-class.html), but there doesn't seem to be any API to directly extract audio level.

I found [this thread](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/671) in flutter-webrtc repo, but it led to no concrete solution.

So, I wonder if anyone has had any success in extracting audio level from webrtc media stream.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question in flutter-webrtc github repo and got a response that eventually led to a solution in my case:

https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/833